# Sign in to iAd workbench

Tags: iad, iad-workbench

Forgive me for asking this here but, I can't sign in to iAd Workbench at all since a few days ago. We have been using it in the company since last year, but now, not even with the main dev account can we log in.

https://iadworkbench.apple.com

I only see this:

> Not Authorized This Apple ID does not have permission to access iAd
>   Workbench. To get started, the iTunes Connect Administrator for your
>   organization needs to sign in and set up your account. Learn More.

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure the user you want to have access has Marketing role access rights:

1. Go to iTunes Connect
2. Manage Users
3. iTunes Connect Users
4. Add New User
5. After entering name and email, select Marketing role.
6. Wait for user to accept role.

Now give the marketer access to the iAd Workbench:

1. Go to iAd Workbench
2. Click triangle next to your name in upper-right corner.
3. Account
4. Users
5. Give the user Reporting, Creation and Admin rights as desired.
6. Save

Tada. Your marketer should now be able to view the iAd Workbench!

Comment: Did you read the question? *We have been using it in the company since last year, but now, not even with the main dev account can we log in.*  **not even with the main dev account can we log in**